# How to write proxy function over funciton?

Tags: javascript, typescript

There is a class with some several methods. One of them:

```
drawGeojson(layerid: string, geojsonObject) {
     this.ngZone.run(() => {}
}
```

How to refactor the code - so that, on request, you can execute the method body with a wrapper

```
 this.ngZone.run(() => {}
```

and without it?

I need something this:

The default call: `drawGeojson()`
The proxy call `Wrapper.drawGeojson();`

Answer (score 0):

If you want conditionally execute

```
this.ngZone.run(() => {})
```

You can add an additional parameter to your method and depend on whether it execute or not.

```
wrapperZone(method: Function, execute: boolean) {
   execute ? this.ngZone.run(() => {
       method()
   }) : method()
}

wrapperZone(this.drawGeojson.bind(this), true)
```

Comment: That is good, by I have to write this conditon in all methods, that not DRY principe

Comment: I think, I understood what you mean, I update the answer, please check.

Comment: Almost, the `this.ngZone.run(() => {})` should contains logic from each function

Comment: I think, you need to pass this code as a third parameter, and pass it to the `ngZone` function, I update the answer.

Comment: `this.ngZone.run(() => {}` should cointain body of function. Each function has own bosy logic

Comment: I update the answer so conditionally use `this.ngZone` and function inside, or just execute the function without.

Comment: Excellent! It is okay, but I want to save API methods names to call outside `drawGeojson(layerid: string, geojsonObject) {}`

Comment: It would be great to call method with wrapper line `Wrapper.method()` and `method()` in default case

Comment: I don't think is possible to use `Wrapper.method()` syntax to call wrapper with the method, as the `Wrapper` in this case should be an object, not a method.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want a decorator function.

```
function makeConditional<T extends unknown[], K>(fn: (...args: T) => K) {
  return function(...args: [...T, boolean]): K | undefined {
  if (args.pop()) {
      return fn(...args as any);
    }
  }
}
```

and then used like

```
drawGeojson = makeConditional(function(layerId: string, geojsonObject: whatever) { ... });
```